# Drawing hierarchy of items with scores

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchy

I am new to Python and programming in general, so would appreciate any help. I am trying to use Python (ideally with the use of Pandas) to do the following:

**Data**

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|    Parent:Child    | Score |
+--------------------+-------+
| Life:Work          |     3 |
| Work:Money         |     2 |
| Work:Hours         |     3 |
| Work:Hours         |     2 |
| Life:Health        |     2 |
| Money:Life savings |     3 |
+--------------------+-------+
```

**Desired Outputs**

1. Table:
   Determine unique items and calculate average scores:

Scores are averaged where there are multiple entries

```
+--------------+---------------+
|  Unique item | Average score |
+--------------+---------------+
| Life         | NaN           |
| Work         | 3             |
| Health       | 2             |
| Money        | 2             |
| Hours        | 2.5           |
| Life savings | 3             |
+--------------+---------------+
```

2. Tree:

a) Determine hierarchy of the items:

Life > Work > Money > Life savings

Life > Work > Hours

Life > Health

b) draw tree with items and average scores:

```
                 Life (NaN)
              /              \
      Work (3)               Health (2)
       /       \  
 Money (2)  Hours (2.5)
      | 
Life savings (3)
```

Some notes:

In the data, colon (":") denotes the relationship between the items. The format is Parent:Child

"Life" has no score, so it should return NaN

"Hours" has two entries in the data, so the average is shown" (2+3)/2 = 2.5

Greatly appreciate your help!

**EDITED**
Thanks AKX for your helpful response. There's just one part which is not solved so I will clarify here. For *2) Tree: a) Determine hierarchy of the items:*

The raw data doesn't specify which layer the Parent:Child is at. The issue here is to write code that can figure this out and link them. From "Life:Work" and "Work:Money", we need to figure out that the child of the first entry ("Work") matches the parent of the second entry ("Money"). ie:

From:
Life:Work
Work:Money

Combines into:
Life:Work:Money

Ultimately, from Raw data:

```
+--------------------+-------+
|    Parent:Child    | Score |
+--------------------+-------+
| Life:Work          |     3 |
| Work:Money         |     2 |
| Work:Hours         |     3 |
| Work:Hours         |     2 |
| Life:Health        |     2 |
| Money:Life savings |     3 |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Create a table like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Layer1 | Layer2 | Layer3 |    Layer4    | Avg Score |                                                             #Comments                                                              |
+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Life   | Work   |        |              | 3         | #Directly from "Life:Work" in raw data                                                                                             |
| Life   | Work   | Money  |              | 2         | #Entry Work:Money has score 2. Since there is an entry "Life:Work", we know "Work" isn't an ultimate parent, and sits below "Life" |
| Life   | Work   | Money  | Life savings | 3         | #Entry "Money:Life savings" has score 3. Similarly, we know from other entries that the hierarchy is Life > Work > Money           |
| Life   | Work   | Hours  |              | 2.5       | #There're entries "Work:Money" and another "Work:Hours", so we know both "Money" and "Hours" are direct children of "Work"         |
| Life   | Health |        |              | 2         | #Directly from "Life:Health" which has score 2. And there is no entry above "Life", which makes it the top of the hierarchy        |
| Life   |        |        |              | NaN       | #There is no entry where "Life" is a child, so "Life" is an ultimate parent. Also, no entry tells us the score for "Life"          |
+--------+--------+--------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then from this table, we should be able to create the tree (format doesn't matter).

```
                 Life (NaN)
              /              \
      Work (3)               Health (2)
       /       \  
 Money (2)  Hours (2.5)
      | 
Life savings (3)
```

Again, appreciate any help!

Comment: There are projects like https://pypi.org/project/asciitree/ that draw the tree for you, if that format is enough for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am not fuzzy about formatting, so the ascitree is good enough. Though my main issue is trying to do the sequence of tasks (ie: determining the unique items, their average scores, their hierarchy, then finally drawing the tree)

Comment: Typo: I meant fussy (not "fuzzy")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thing using that `asciitree` library I mentioned.

Turns out it made it rather easy to print out a custom value for each tree node, which is exactly what we wanted here.

I tried to add helpful comments where I could.

```py
from asciitree import LeftAligned, DictTraversal

import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict


class ShowValueTraversal(DictTraversal):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def get_text(self, node):
        key = node[0]
        if key in self.values:
            return f"{key} ({self.values[key]})"
        return key


def treeify(averages_dict):
    # Make a recursive tree we can just add children to
    make_tree = lambda: defaultdict(make_tree)
    tree = make_tree()

    for tag, value in averages_dict.items():
        parent = tree
        parts = tag.split(":")
        for i in range(len(parts) + 1):
            joined_tag = ":".join(parts[:i])
            parent = parent[joined_tag]
    return tree


def fixup_names(dct):
    # Break down the keys on colons
    dct = {tuple(key.split(":")): value for (key, value) in dct.items()}
    # Get a mapping of the last "atoms" of each known name to their full name
    last_atom_map = {p[-1]: p for p in dct}

    # Walk through the original dictionary, replacing any known first atom with
    # an entry from the last atom map if possible and reconstitute the keys
    new_dct = {}
    for key, value in dct.items():
        key_parts = list(key)
        while key_parts[0] in last_atom_map:
            # Slice in the new prefix
            key_parts[0:1] = last_atom_map[key_parts[0]]
        new_key = ":".join(key_parts)
        new_dct[new_key] = value
    return new_dct


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("Life:Work", 3),
        ("Work:Money", 2),
        ("Work:Hours", 3),
        ("Work:Hours", 2),
        ("Life:Health", 2),
        ("Money:Life savings", 3),
        ("Money:Something", 2),
        ("Money:Something:Deeper", 1),
    ],
    columns=["tag", "value"],
)

print("# Original data")
print(df)
print()

print("# Averages")
df_averages = df.groupby("tag").mean()
print(df_averages)
print()

# Turn the averages into a dict of tag -> value
averages_dict = dict(df_averages.itertuples())

# Fix up the names (to infer hierarchy)
averages_dict = fixup_names(averages_dict)

# Generate a tree out of the flat data
tree = treeify(averages_dict)
# Instantiate a custom asciitree traversal object that knows how to
# look up the values from the dict
traverse = ShowValueTraversal(values=averages_dict)

# Print it out!
print("# Tree")
print(LeftAligned(traverse=traverse)(tree))
```

The output is

```
# Original data
                      tag  value
0               Life:Work      3
1              Work:Money      2
2              Work:Hours      3
3              Work:Hours      2
4             Life:Health      2
5      Money:Life savings      3
6         Money:Something      2
7  Money:Something:Deeper      1

# Averages
                        value
tag
Life:Health               2.0
Life:Work                 3.0
Money:Life savings        3.0
Money:Something           2.0
Money:Something:Deeper    1.0
Work:Hours                2.5
Work:Money                2.0

# Tree

 +-- Life
     +-- Life:Health (2.0)
     +-- Life:Work (3.0)
         +-- Life:Work:Money (2.0)
         |   +-- Life:Work:Money:Life savings (3.0)
         |   +-- Life:Work:Money:Something (2.0)
         |       +-- Life:Work:Money:Something:Deeper (1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. One of the feature of the data is that is sometimes doesn't list out the whole hierarchy. For example:
Data:
Money:Something (3)
Something:Deeper (2)

And the code is able to work out that the tree is Money:Something:Deeper. And outputs:
+-- Money
     +-- Something (3.0)
          +-- Deeper (2.0)

Comment: The intermediate nodes should still appear in the tree just fine. Do they not?

Comment: I think my problem statement on building the hierarchy might have not been clear. I've added to the bottom of my original post an elaboration on this specific point. Thanks!

Comment: @LondonStreet Okay, I added a `fixup_names` function that can infer the deeper hierarchy! :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much